# Mixed-effect models - too many random factor categories - how to solve?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, many-categories

I'm attempting to specify several random effects in a `lme/lmer`. In specific, I have conducted an experiment where I have stimulated several test animals with other animals that belong to two groups (treated/untreated stimulus animals - the variable specifying stimulus treatment is called Stimulusgroup). Due to a lack of animals, I have had to re-use some of the stimulus animals. Test animals were used only once with two stimulus animals each - hence I have two values per test animal (Response to Stimulus animal 1 and response to Stimulus animal two). Hence I need to include both `TestanimalID` and `StimulusanimalID`.

Therefore my model looks like this:

```
lme(Response ~ Stimulusgroup,
    random=~1|StimulusanimalID/TestanimalID,
    data=x, method="ML")
```

However, when running this model I receive the following error code:

> number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

I would like to know if there is a way to still conduct the analysis as the reviewers of my paper have explicitly asked for inclusion of these two random effects in my models. I have heard that one may use `cbind` in this case but I did not find anything online.

Comment: Why do you believe you need a nested random effect? From what I understand from your description, you should use two uncorrelated random effects, e.g. in lme4 syntax `(1 | StimulusanimalID) + (1 | TestanimalID)`. But I admit that I haven't fully understood your description.

Comment: The experiment itself is a mate-choice set-up where the test animal can choose between two stimulus animals at the same time. Thus, the response towards one stimulus animal is always dependent of which other stimulus animal it was paired with and both have to be coupled by "TestanimalID" or - in other words - by "ExperimentID" (which is the same as every test animal was used only once). Only the stimulus animals are used multiple times for several test animals/ in several experiments (each stimulusanimalID appears in several "TestanimalID"/"ExperimentID"). This requires nested random effects.

Comment: You probably need one of the pdMat structures in nlme to describe your dependency structure. What you have now is not correct because not every test animal was paired with every stimulus animal. Your dependency matrix is much sparser. Can't help you with the details, since I usually have simpler random effects.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I got your question right.. you have two sets of animals one used just once and the other used twice . I think you can just use animal as a factor and fit response =(1|animal) in the lmer syntax. You will have to switch  to the lme4 package since, if my memory serves me right, me requires that you have more than one observation per group. Lmer lets you fit observation level random effects. Perhaps @benbolker might jump in and give you some hints here. 
EDIT: After reading the comments below.. this is my understanding of the experimental design ( will edit if it needs refinement). For each test animal there are two observations associated with different stimulus animals. Some of these stimulus animals are re-used.. that is some test animals had encounters with the same stimulus animals. OP originally wanted to fit a nested model with testAnimalID nested within stimulusID. Nested effects can also be considered as maineffect+interaction , so in this case it would be something like `(1|stimulusID)+ (1|stimulusID*testAnimalID)`. The first part will account for correlated observations, however the second part will be equivalent to observation level random effects not covariance among observations from the same testAnimalID. I agree with @rolands comment above that it would be simpler to just fit a random effect for each id i.e `(1|stimulusID)+ (1|testAnimalID)`.

Comment: To make the example easier to visualize, here's an image. Every TestID animal was used only once with 2 StimulusID animals at the same time. StimulusID animals were sometimes (but not always) re-used: http://i.imgur.com/YxfrOK3.png Switching to the lme4 package wouldn't be the problem. I'm just concerned how about to correctly fit the random effects as a simple nested or crossed set-up seems to be incorrect. In your example you are referring to using "animal" as a factor - are you referring to TestanimalID or StimulusanimalID here?

Comment: Generally I'm concerned with effects of the treatment of the stimulus animal ("Stimulusgroup") rather than its ID - I just want to control for possible effects of re-using some stimulus animals (hence StimulusID as a random effect)

Comment: By animal I meant an Id for each animal irrespective of which group they belong to so that you will capture correlations in observations from the same animal .. sort of a repeated measures.. expect that in your case some animals are repeated and some are not

Comment: Testanimals have never been used as stimulusanimals and only the responses of the testanimals were measured. Hence I'm not sure that is the correct approach, could you confirm?

Comment: Yes .. correct... I think you will just use stimulusid as the random effect... I will edit the answer accordingly in a little bit

Comment: How then do you account for the fact that you have two responses (values) per testanimal (one response towards one stimulus animal and the second towards the second stimulus animal)? Your proposition sounds like the correct solution for when every test animal was exposed to just one stimulus animal.

Comment: I think i understand your design better now.. have edited my answer

Comment: Hope the edit was helpful

Comment: In lmer, nested effects would be '(1|testAnimalID/stimulusID)'. If '(1|StimulusID) + (1|testAnimalID)' sufficiently represent my data, that would be great. However, to my knowledge this would be crossed random effects that assume complete independency - which is not necessarily true for my case. Now, I have an additional issue as my PI told me to also include 'TestanimalFamily' to account for possible genetic effects. As there are always several TestanimalIDs per Testanimalfamily, they need to be nested. '(1|stimulusID) + (1|testanimalFamilly/testAnimalID)' ?